# create a gradient fill cell

Tags: java, excel, apache

I need to create a gradient fill cell like the picture below using Apache POI.

I used this code to create a simple gradient fill, but i need exactly like in picture.

Thank you all for your help.

PS: picture shows, what i mean by gradient fill cell.

[image: xls file]

```
                XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();

                Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet();

                Row row = sheet.createRow(0);
                XSSFCellStyle cellstyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
                //set pattern fill settings only to have some fill to get the fill index from it
                cellstyle.setFillPattern(FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND);

                //get fill index used in this CellStyle
                int fillidx = (int)cellstyle.getCoreXf().getFillId();

                //get the low level CTFill used in this CellStyle
                CTFill ctfill = workbook.getStylesSource().getFillAt(fillidx).getCTFill();
                System.out.println(ctfill);

                //unset the pattern fill
                ctfill.unsetPatternFill();

                //now low level set the gradient fill
                byte[] rgb1 = new byte[3];
                rgb1[0] = (byte) 0; // red
                rgb1[1] = (byte) 102; // green
                rgb1[2] = (byte) 102; // blue

                byte[] rgb2 = new byte[3];
                rgb2[0] = (byte) 255; // red
                rgb2[1] = (byte) 255; // green
                rgb2[2] = (byte) 255; // blue

                CTGradientFill ctgradientfill = ctfill.addNewGradientFill();
                ctgradientfill.setDegree(45.0);
                ctgradientfill.addNewStop().setPosition(0.0);
                ctgradientfill.getStopArray(0).addNewColor().setRgb(rgb1);
                ctgradientfill.addNewStop().setPosition(0.9);
                ctgradientfill.getStopArray(1).addNewColor().setRgb(rgb2);
                ctgradientfill.addNewStop().setPosition(1.0);
                ctgradientfill.getStopArray(2).addNewColor().setRgb(rgb1);
                System.out.println(ctfill);

                Cell cell = row.createCell(0);
                cell.setCellValue("");
                cell.setCellStyle(cellstyle);

                workbook.write(new FileOutputStream("C:/file.xlsx"));
                workbook.close();
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: Try the Excel macro recorder and see the code it generates. Then mimic the code to yours and it will be exactly as in the picture.

Comment: the generated code its just for events and actions not for style. thanks for your help

Comment: See my answer & give it a try.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
Sub gradient()
'
' gradient Macro
'

'
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlPatternRectangularGradient
        .gradient.RectangleLeft = 1
        .gradient.RectangleRight = 1
        .gradient.RectangleTop = 0
        .gradient.RectangleBottom = 0
        .gradient.ColorStops.Clear
    End With
    With Selection.Interior.gradient.ColorStops.Add(0)
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    With Selection.Interior.gradient.ColorStops.Add(1)
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent5
        .TintAndShade = -0.498031556138798
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @Vityata this is my generated macro of my gradient cell

Answer (score 0):

This is generated code for gradient fill through Macro Recorder:

```
Sub Makro3()
'
' Makro3 Makro
'

'
    Range("A1").Select
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlPatternLinearGradient
        .Gradient.Degree = 45
        .Gradient.ColorStops.Clear
    End With
    With Selection.Interior.Gradient.ColorStops.Add(0)
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    With Selection.Interior.Gradient.ColorStops.Add(1)
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent1
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=4
End Sub
```

Simply press the red dot for <kbd>Record Macro</kbd> and make your own gradient fill. MS Excel will generate the code for you.

Comment: ...
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlPatternRectangularGradient
        .Gradient.RectangleLeft = 1
        .Gradient.RectangleRight = 1
        .Gradient.RectangleTop = 0
        .Gradient.RectangleBottom = 0
        .Gradient.ColorStops.Clear
    End With
    With Selection.Interior.Gradient.ColorStops.Add(0)
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    With Selection.Interior.Gradient.ColorStops.Add(1)
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent5
        .TintAndShade = -0.498031556138798
...

Comment: @becherhenchiri - what is this?

Comment: this is my generated macro of my gradient cell

Comment: @becherhenchiri - so I suppose that you did use the macro recorder?

Comment: yes i used it, check my answer with the generated code i have added it

Comment: not yet, i want to convert or rewrite the vba macro code to java with appache poi

Answer (score 0):

Try to get what you want with record macro, then play and see how it work
but if fail, you can edit manually with this reference [VBA Code Cell Fills (Color, Patterns, & Gradients)](https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/the-code-vault/2014/2/27/cell-fills-color-patterns-gradients)